# Set up a conditional cmd.run based on file.managed in SaltStack

Tags: salt-stack

I have a SaltStack state file (sls) that has a pretty simple state defined.

```
MyStateRule:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://scripts/rule.ps1
    - name: 'c:\scripts\rule.ps1'
  cmd.run:
    - name: powershell c:\scripts\rule.ps1
    - require:
      - file: MyStateRule
```

When I run a *state.apply* command, the *cmd.run* appears to execute every time, which I can see makes sense. What I want is to only run when the managed file needs to be copied over to the minion. Can I use *file.managed* in that case? What do I need to change, such that the script only runs when the file is copied over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it -- rather than using "require," use onchanges:

```
cmd.run:
  - name: powershell c:\scripts\rule.ps1
  - onchanges:
    - file: MyStateRule
```